# how can i make my progress bar refresh, and let it load automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that starts working on click, and it doesn't refresh automatically.
How do I make it refresh and load automatically, here's my code:
If someone could help me, that would be great!
I also need it to last for 20 seconds.

```
    <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="test.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
    <div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
    <div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0%</div>
    </div>

    <p>Click once to start!</p>
    <p>Click again to toggle Start/Stop</p>

    <script>
    var timer = 0,
        perc = 0,
        timeTotal = 2500,
        timeCount = 1,
        cFlag;

    function updateProgress(percentage) {
        var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
            y = x.toFixed(3);
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
        $('#pbar_innertext').text(y + "%");
    }

    function animateUpdate() {
        if(perc < timeTotal) {
            perc++;
            updateProgress(perc);
            timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
            if (cFlag == undefined) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                perc = 0;
                cFlag = true;
                animateUpdate();
            }
            else if (!cFlag) {
                cFlag = true;
                animateUpdate();
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                cFlag = false;
            }
        });
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to trigger the click when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
    // some code to handle click
  });
  
  $("#pbar_outerdiv").trigger( "click" );  // this will get the progressbar working as soon as the DOM is loaded
  
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1hatjLe3/)

Read about triggering events in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @pieterbesje Use `location.reload();` for that. If you are satisfied with this answer, please mark this as accepted.

Comment: so can you make a quick demo to show me, cuz when i use location.reload(); , it refreshes every second.

Comment: @pieterbesje [Here is a demo about it.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_reload) Please post your complete code that is refreshing at every second so that I can take a look.

Comment: @Rehul Desai I used this code, and now it works, it refreshes every 20 seconds.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 20000);

Comment: @Rehul Desai , it refreshes the whole page though, i just need it to refresh the progress bar.

Comment: @pieterbesje Why do you need to refresh the progressbar? It is updating anyway, isnt it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65679/discussion-between-pieterbesje-and-rahul-desai).